# MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync exception "Value cannot be null, parameter name: token"

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to make an API Call on a .NET backend like this:

**client side (c#)**

```
await client.InvokeApiAsync<UserProfile>(
    "UserInfo",
    System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
    null);
```

**backend side (UserInfoController.cs)**

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<MySkiSchool.DataObjects.UserProfile> Get()
{
    [...]
    var curUser = context.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
    [...]
    return curUser;
}
```

But I get an exception wich mesagge is: *"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: token"*.

I've already checked with fiddler if I can get some more info, but nothing passes through fiddler during that call.

Could someone tell me what this token refers to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for clarity the user seems to be currently and correctly logged in as MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser has both the UserID and  the MobileServiceAuthenticationToken populated

Comment: I had further investigated and I get this exception only when I use the backend on localhost, with the authentication managed on the cloud. To achieve this I've followed this article step by step: http://www.systemsabuse.com/2015/12/04/local-debugging-with-user-authentication-of-an-azure-mobile-app-service/

Comment: if that resolved your problem, you may want to consider adding that as an answer and marking it as so in order to help others.

Comment: No, the problem is not solved, as I need to debug my mobile app on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

This documentation provides step-by-step instructions on debugging auth with a locally deployed service:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Local-development-and-debugging-the-Mobile-App-.NET-server-backend

I hope this helps.